# Search Excel for duplicate cells

Tags: excel, oracle, excel-formula

I have data columns of an order_items table stored in Excel file. The table is about 1 million rows long and contains columns item_id, order_id, price and quantity. In addition to that, I have an Oracle database which is built so, that primary key is combined from item_id and order_id.

When I try to import the data into an Oracle table, I get errors that the primary key is violated. Since I generated the table data randomly, then there may be some cases in million rows, where one order contains the same product multiple times.

I'm able to sort the data by either column, but I wouldn't like to go through all those million rows by hand, so could anyone tell me what would be the easiest way to find multiple rows in excel, which have same item_id (labeled A) and order_id (labeled B) columns.

Comment: I found that one way to do something similar is through pivot tables. Now I'm able to group all the items that are in the same order. Still, I have 100000 orders, from which I would like to exclude the ones where there are no duplicates.

Comment: A better approach is to import the data into a temporary table, then you can run a simpole query to find duplicates before loading it into your target table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple using COUNTIFS

I am assuming that row 1 is header row and E is the next blank column

in E2 use the formula

```
  =COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

Fill this formula down the column

[image]

Anything in Col E > 1 is a an item that appears more than once on that order

[image]

Be careful of quantity and price differences, you may want to combine the rows into 1 before deleting the duplicate rows

The formula will then update to a 1 if you delete the duplicates

**Remember you are using COUNT - so all rows with the same item_id and order_id will have a count > 1 , not just the 2nd( or more) found rows**
( so don't just go and immediately delete all these rows as you will being deleting the original and dups)

Comment: This seems like the proper solution, although it will probably take alot of time for it to go through all the rows. I let it run for some time and it didn't go past the 0% marker. As 1000 rows took it about 1 minute to calculate, then I don't want to know how long a million rows will take. Seems like I have to go back to data generation and solve the issue at that stage.

Comment: it took 3 mins on my laptop to do 1000000 rows, onces its done once you could copy/paste special values that column.  Do you want a VBA solution, it would be faster?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of this from first principles suggests that sorting would be a good idea because Excel's sort algorithm is fast and should execute in NlogN (base 2) time so you would be talking about 20,000,000 operations for a million rows which will take a few seconds to run.

So first sort jointly on Item_ID and Order_ID.

Then you could just use a linear comparison method to detect duplicate rows using a formula like

```
=AND(A2=A1,B2=B1)
```

[image]